# PHP on WAMP: problems uploading / creating a file

Tags: php, file-upload, wampserver

I get this error and I am not sure how to clear it.  Not sure if its on my WAMP and if so I have two ini file, development and production, where should I look?

```
( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploadedFiles/gal2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\fileupload.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  257960  {main}( )   ..\fileupload.php:0
2   0.0015  303448  move_uploaded_file ( )  ..\fileupload.php:20

( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php71A.tmp' to 'uploadedFiles/gal2.jpg' in C:\wamp\www\fileupload.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  257960  {main}( )   ..\fileupload.php:0
2   0.0015  303448  move_uploaded_file ( )  ..\fileupload.php:20
```

The code is below:

```
$desiredPath = 'uploadedFiles/';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    print "Picture Info"."<br>";
    print_r($_FILES['picture']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $desiredPath.$_FILES['picture']['name']))
    {
        print 'File Upload Successful';
        print '<div>';
        print '<img width="300px" src="'.$desiredPath.$_FILES['picture']['name'].'">';
        print '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        print 'File Upload Failed with error code: '.$_FILES['picture']['error'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the folder has proper write permissions. Either 0755 or 0777. Also make sure that your folder is indeed named `uploadedFiles` and not `uploadedfiles`. It matters on UNIX/LINUX systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$desiredPath = 'uploadedFiles/';
```

Have you tested that the directory exists, before moving the file to it?
Code below:

```
if(!file_exists($desiredPath)) {
    mkdir($desiredPath, 0755, true);
}
```

It's just a suggestion. I was trying to create an upload script myself and that little block of code solved all my problems